# Reading a simple Avro file from HDFS

Tags: java, io, avro

I am trying to do a simple read of an Avro file stored in HDFS.  I found out how to read it when it is on the local file system....

```
FileReader reader = DataFileReader.openReader(new File(filename), new GenericDatumReader());

for (GenericRecord datum : fileReader) {
   String value = datum.get(1).toString();
   System.out.println("value = " value);
}

reader.close();
```

My file is in HDFS, however.  I cannot give the openReader a Path or an FSDataInputStream.  How can I simply read an Avro file in HDFS?

EDIT:  I got this to work by creating a custom class (SeekableHadoopInput) that implements SeekableInput.  I "stole" this from "Ganglion" on github.  Still, seems like there would be a Hadoop/Avro integration path for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [FsInput](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.3/api/java/org/apache/avro/mapred/FsInput.html) class (in the avro-mapred submodule, since it depends on Hadoop) can do this. It provides the seekable input stream that is needed for Avro data files.

```
Path path = new Path("/path/on/hdfs");
Configuration config = new Configuration(); // make this your Hadoop env config
SeekableInput input = new FsInput(path, config);
DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>();
FileReader<GenericRecord> fileReader = DataFileReader.openReader(input, reader);

for (GenericRecord datum : fileReader) {
    System.out.println("value = " + datum);
}

fileReader.close(); // also closes underlying FsInput
```